# Will these suspensions fit my bike

Tags: mountain-bike

I want to get this suspension

SR Suntour XCR-RL 26inch Suspension Fork. Black, 120mm Travel, Remote Lockout, Disc Brake Only

But I don't know will it for my bike and also what's the difference between hydraulic and Coil suspension.

My bike is the 
Falcon Renegade Mens Mountain Bike 19

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will the SR Suntour Suspension fit my bike](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/34509/will-the-sr-suntour-suspension-fit-my-bike)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main criteria for determining fork fit are:

- steerer tube diameter (1" or 1 1/8")
- steerer tube length
- steerer tube type (threaded or threadless)
- wheel size
- brake type

Suspension travel can also come into play as the frame was designed for a fork of a given length. Deviating from this length by adding or subtracting suspension travel can affect the handling characteristics. How much it will affect it is a subject of much debate. I think if you stay with 20mm of stock you are most likely ok.

The fork on your bike appears in the photos to be a  1-1/8 inch steerer and at the price point it sells at it is most likely a straight steerer, (some are 1-1/2" at the crown and 1-1/8" at the top). The disc brakes are a match as is the wheel size. The XCR is a step up from the Zoom fork listed as the stock piece for your bike, but it is still considered an entry level fork. As long as you limit it to entry level abuse it should work fine.

The advantage of a spring fork over a rigid fork is you gain some compression dampening. The fork compresses to absorb impacts and vibration. You generally don't get any rebound dampening. The fork will extend at the same rate it compressed. A hydraulic fork can give you controlled compression and controlled  extension.

Comment: Will the SR Suntour nvx-MLO 700C suspension fork 255mm Ahead black.Disc brake only by SR Suntour fit my bike

Comment: This fork is classified as a "city" fork by Suntour, my guess is it is not designed for off road use.The 700c fork will be longer and this may effect handling. You may also not have sufficient tire side clearance for mountain bike tires. The 255mm is an uncut steerer.  Unless you currently have an XXL frame the steerer will have to be cut or additional headset spacers needed.

Comment: What would be a good suspension with lockout from my bike